# Change Annotation Image in Mapbox Cluster

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I need to show different UIImages for each annotation when it is unclustered.
I have had little luck over the past few days.

Using Swift 4 - Decodable...

```
feature.properties.imageName
```

Gives me the imageName from my GeoJSON

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
         {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties":
         {
             "scalerank": 8,
             "name": "Grill",
             "website": "www.rocargo.com/SanNicolas.html",
             "natlscale": 5,
             "imageName": "port"
             },
         "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [
                             -21.1143603,
                             47.1448965
                             ]
             }
             },
```

The code below is mostly taken from MapBox.  I'm trying to look at each GeoJSON and take the appropriate imageName.  Then use this for my Image Annotation.
Can anyone help me with my code below please?  I did find some information from 
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8817
talking about NSPredicate but I couldn't figure it out.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bars", ofType: "geojson")!)

    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",
                                url: url,
                                options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])

    style.addSource(source)

    let portsIcon = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "ports", source: source)

    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Collection.self, from: jsonData)

        for feature in result.features {

            let iconName = UIImage(named: feature.properties.imageName as String)
            style.setImage((iconName?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))!, forName: feature.properties.imageName as String)
            portsIcon.iconImageName = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: feature.properties.imageName as NSString)
            portsIcon.iconColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.9))
            portsIcon.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != YES", "cluster")

            print("name in Fish", feature.properties.name, "featureclass", feature.properties.imageName)
        }
    } catch { print("Error while parsing: \(error)") }

    style.addLayer(portsIcon)

    // Color clustered features based on clustered point counts.
    let stops = [
        20:  MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.lightGray),
        50:  MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.orange),
        100: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.red),
        200: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.purple)
    ]

    // Show clustered features as circles. The `point_count` attribute is built into clustering-enabled source features.

    let circlesLayer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPorts", source: source)
    circlesLayer.circleRadius = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))

    circlesLayer.circleOpacity = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 0.75)
    circlesLayer.circleStrokeColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.75))
    circlesLayer.circleStrokeWidth = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 2)
    circlesLayer.circleColor = MGLSourceStyleFunction(interpolationMode: .interval,
                                                      stops: stops,
                                                      attributeName: "point_count",
                                                      options: nil)
    circlesLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", "cluster")
    style.addLayer(circlesLayer)

    // Label cluster circles with a layer of text indicating feature count. Per text token convention, wrap the attribute in {}.
    let numbersLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPortsNumbers", source: source)
    numbersLayer.textColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.white)
    numbersLayer.textFontSize = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))

    numbersLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: true)
    numbersLayer.text = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "{point_count}")
    numbersLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", "cluster")
    style.addLayer(numbersLayer)

    // Add a tap gesture for zooming in to clusters or showing popups on individual features.
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:))))
}
```

Comment: In your do - catch block, which print statement fires?

Comment: Its always "name in fish..."  So that part of code works fine.
I think it is with         
`style.addLayer(portsIcon)`
If I put that inside after 
`portsIcon.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != YES", "cluster")`
It pulls up an error as it can't add in multiple layers.

Comment: What do you see when you zoom to uncluster? Do your unclustered icons all have one of your images but the same image?

Comment: Yes thats correct.  The unclustered images show one of my images and they are the same one.

Comment: It looks like the MGLSymbolStyleLayer can handle only one icon. The loop in your do - catch block appears to set it to each of your icons in turn but overwrites the previous value, leaving you with the final icon of the loop. I'd recommend getting in touch with Mapbox they've always been helpful when I've contacted them before. Maybe there is something we're missing. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch with me Magnas.  I sent MapBox an email, hopefully they'll get in touch. Cheers

Comment: @M.Strachan Good day, I stuck over here as well. May I know got any update from Mapbox? Or how u going to solve this case?